# how to reduce the size of listview width using xml in android?

Tags: android

how to `reduce` the size of listview width by using  xml in android?

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive when you ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you'd edit the `android:layout_width` parameter...  is there something I'm missing?

For example this ListView is limited to being 200 dip wide:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="200dip" />
```